# configuring Hibernate, stripersist on eclipse

Tags: hibernate, stripes

I have tried to use stripersist with mysql but was not successful.

I have copied sample code of stripes book , email23 , to eclipse and added res folder as source folder.

When I try to run the application I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stripesbook.dao.impl.stripersist.BaseDaoImpl.read(BaseDaoImpl.java:46)
    at stripesbook.ext.MyActionBeanContext.getUser(MyActionBeanContext.java:60)
    at stripesbook.action.BaseActionBean.getUser(BaseActionBean.java:93)
    at stripesbook.action.ContactListActionBean.getContacts(ContactListActionBean.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:83)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005flist_jsp._jspService(contact_005flist_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.action.ForwardResolution.execute(ForwardResolution.java:110)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$7.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:483)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.HttpCacheInterceptor.intercept(HttpCacheInterceptor.java:99)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.executeResolution(DispatcherHelper.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.executeResolution(DispatcherServlet.java:293)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doPost(DispatcherServlet.java:177)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doGet(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I have checked this thread, [Help configuring Hibernate,Jpa, Stripesist on Stripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740573/help-configuring-hibernate-jpa-stripesist-on-stripes) , but still have the problem

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would assume Stripersist is null in that case, which means that it didn't start up right.  Do you get any stacktrace on startup concerning Stripersist?  Any logs about stripersist starting up successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing on the getEntityManager() that returns null:

```
45: public T read(ID id) {
46:    return Stripersist.getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
47: }
```

This means that you don't have Hibernate/JPA configured correctly for your web application.

You might find this documentation helpful (although you can follow any Hibernate/JPA configuration guide, as the configuration is not Stripersist or Stripes specific):
http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Hibernate+configuration